# In e-mail, is there such a thing as a "to string"?

Tags: email

When you get an e-mail, there is the concept of a "from" string/header, such as this:

```
Arbitrary Name <email@address.com>
```

There is no separate "name" header; it's extracted from this "from" string/header.

Is there a similar "to" string/header, for when you *send* an e-mail?

That is, is it possible to send an e-mail to:

```
Insulting Nickname <email.address.com>
```

Instead of to:

```
email.address.com
```

? And if so, will that `Insulting Nickname` show up in their e-mail client?

Or is it, as I think, impossible to send an e-mail to anything other than a pure e-mail address?

Comment: Yes, and it depends on the email client. See RFC 5322.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How can it depend on the client? How is it interpreted by a non-supporting client, then?

Answer (score 1):

Both `To` and `From` headers could be anything, as they are not really used for delivering the message: in the SMTP protocol there's ([RFC 5321, 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.3)):

- a separate *envelope sender* used in `MAIL FROM` command and
- one or more recipients in `RCPT TO` command, as it can be repeated multiple times.

While DMARC can protect domains from spoofing in the `From` header and SPF in the `MAIL FROM` command, there's really nothing that prevents you from using not only arbitrary names but also arbitrary email addresses in the `To` header. That doesn't even require a software crafted specially for that purpose, because you could simply put the real address in the *blind carbon copy* `Bcc` field and something else or nothing in the `To` field.